# Check Job Status : Mapreduce Job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to check jobstatus of a Mapreduce Job.

When I run `job.iscomplete()` , I get exception 
`"Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING"` .

```
try {
                    if (job.isComplete()) {
                        printInfoLog(LOG, this.filename,
                                "** " + job.getTrackingURL());
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.warn("** " + e.getMessage());

                }
```

But there is no such state as I checked all the fields in `Jobstatus(https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobStatus.html)`

I kind of understand it by the feeling that the job is not yet submitted . Can anyone please suggest me how to check whether job is submitted or not as I could not find any such method in the `API`.

Comment: `mapred` is the old API. `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` is the new one.

Comment: I checked the latest API also , I could not find state DEFINE

Comment: In the YARN UI, are you able to see the job? Can you please add your code to the question?

Comment: I solved by putting a condition before try catch block, which says if job is running / failed / succeeded / killed then  proceed otherwise continue monitoring job in a infite loop

Comment: Please put your solution as an answer below so it may help others

Answer (score 0):

I solved it as follows,

```
if ( job.getJobState() == JobStatus.State.RUNNING || job.getJobState() == JobStatus.State.SUCCEEDED || job.getJobState() == JobStatus.State.KILLED || job.getJobState() == JobStatus.State.FAILED)
{
try {
        if (job.isComplete()) {
        printInfoLog(LOG, this.filename,
                            "** " + job.getTrackingURL());
         break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOG.warn("** " + e.getMessage());

                }
}
}
```

Although i do agree its a crude solution